# Where can a 300lb person get a spin endorsement in Miami?

Tags: aerobatics, cfi, spins, logbook-endorsements

I'm in Miami Working on my CFI, I'm at the level of trying to get my spin endorsement. The problem is I'm 6'2" and 300lb, so I need your help.

Comment: Paraphrasing a classic movie ... "We're gonna need a bigger plane"

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Comment: Find a spin-training class that uses something bigger than a 150 Aerobat. Here in WI there is a guy conducting upset training in a E33c Bonanza.

Comment: where can I do my spin endorsement in a big plane @GdD ?